# last-child не работает как хотелось бы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть куча блоков в `.main`, надо применить стиль к последнему `.one`
Но блок `.two` мешает этому

JS использовать не хочется, контент динамический и это будет создавать проблемы

```css
.main {} .main .one {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #4679BD;
  border: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
.main .one:last-child {
  border: none;
}
.main .two {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>

  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1hqadwu/)

Comment: По идее Вам нужен .main .one:last-of-type, но мне так и не удалось заставить его сработать в FF.

Comment: Нормально `:last-of-type` работает в FF. Зачем его заставлять. Другое дело, что в спецификации только для `:only-of-type` написано "...siblings with the same element name", а в других `:...-of-type` написано "...sibling of its type" и понимай как хочешь. А браузеры понимают именно как "среди элементов с одинаковым именем" и селектор класса применяются уже после выбора элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно все Ваши "one" заключить еще в 1 див с идентификатором, а потом конкретно уже сделать

```
<div id="dv">
<div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
</div>

#dv .one:last-child{
border:0px
}
```

Comment: Дичное решение, но ничего другого кажется нет, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1**

Если блок `.two` всегда есть и он один, воспользуйтесь `:nth-last-child(2)`

**Вариант 2**

Подсказано пользователем @Mik. С учетом тонкостей работы псевдокласса `:last-of-type` можно изменить верстку так, чтобы `.two` были другими тегами (например `<p class="two"></p>`) или уже можно воспользоваться произвольными тегами (например `<two></two>`, при этом обязательно указать в css свойство `display`) Гугл и Яндекс уже применяют и не стесняются.